# How Spring JPA transactions store data before commit

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

Lets say I need to create 100.000 records and than `.save()` them. All records should be saved together and only one transaction is allowed. Clearly, this is a problem and program can run out of memory. But what will happen if I will do the same work in the same transaction but in chunks? 1000 records per iteration and than I save them. Will it fix the problem? Intuitively I think it will not and design is wrong. What happens with entities after I `.save()`? Does JPA still keep references to all saved entities? Where can I read more on this topic? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what will happen if I will do the same work in the same transaction but in chunks? 1000 records per iteration and than I save them. Will it fix the problem?

It will fix the problem if you use the following approach:

```java
while (hasNextBatch()) {
    saveBatch();
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.clear();
}
```

> What happens with entities after I .save()? Does JPA still keep references to all saved entities?

Yes (unless you do the above).

> Where can I read more on this topic?

[Here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-first-level-cache/), for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Short and to the point.